# POST returns 404 when the API route exists within my files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I am trying to get a fetch to an API route within my files, I'm trying to create a record using inputs from a form with Prisma to my Postgres DB. I've written my fetch request but it returns a 404 stating that it cannot find the route, here is my directory:
[My file path, the page.tsx labeled here is where my fetch request is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZQsA.png)

```
"use client";
import styles from "./page.module.css";
import QClientProvider from "./imports/QClientProvider";
import { useState } from "react";
/* PAGE COMPONENT IMPORTS */

import Chapters from "./components/chapters/Chapters";

/* PAGE COMPONENT IMPORTS */

export default function Home() {
  const [chapterVal, setChapter] = useState("");
  const [verseVal, setVerse] = useState("");
  const [contentVal, setContent] = useState("");

  const handleChapterChange = (event) => {
    setChapter(event?.target.value);
  };

  const handleVerseChange = (event) => {
    setVerse(event?.target.value);
  };

  const handleContentChange = (event) => {
    setContent(event?.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("/api/createInterpretations", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(chapterVal),
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <QClientProvider>
        <main className={styles.main}>
          <div className={styles.verses}>
            <Chapters />
          </div>
          <form>
            <label>
              Chapter Number:{" "}
              <input
                type="text"
                value={chapterVal}
                onChange={handleChapterChange}
              />
            </label>
            <label>
              Verse Number:{" "}
              <input
                type="text"
                value={verseVal}
                onChange={handleVerseChange}
              />
            </label>
            <label>
              Interpretation Contents:{" "}
              <input
                type="text"
                value={contentVal}
                onChange={handleContentChange}
              />
            </label>
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit!</button>
          </form>
        </main>
      </QClientProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is my createInterpretations.tsx

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { prisma } from "@/lib/prisma";

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    console.log("POST Methods ONLY.");
  }

  const toSend = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const newInterpretation = await prisma.interpretations.create({
    data: toSend,
  });
};
```

I tried creating a different function to be exported, then tried importing that into my page.tsx and copying the auto-complete path, which did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey looks like you are using the NextJS 13 app router. All API routes are handled via [Route Handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#convention), thus if you want to fetch `/api/createInterpretations`, you must create a subdirectory with a route.ts file like this `src/app/api/createInterpretations/route.ts`.

`route.ts`

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { prisma } from "@/lib/prisma";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const toSend = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const newInterpretation = await prisma.interpretations.create({
    data: toSend,
  });
 
  return NextResponse.json(newInterpretation) // return a valid javascript object
}
```